# NuGet Package Manager Console autocompletion suggests all files from PATH

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2012, autocomplete, nuget

Here's an example:

[image: NuGet Console autocompletion suggests]

You can see that NuGet's own commands are hidden among all these files (probably all the files from PATH folders) in autocomplete suggestions. Should it be that way or have I broken something?

**UPD**: anyway, how can I get rid of these suggestions?

(Win7 x64, VS2012-Update 2, NuGet 2.5)

Answer (score 2):

That's normal. The stand alone PowerShell host does the same thing. When there is no context hints for what should be tab-completed, it will enumerate stuff in the current directory.

Comment: tab completion is fully customizable ;)